# session timeout due to inactivity + alert box

Tags: php

i am looking for solution of my answer which is half completed i have to make the user logout from my website and i used your solution which is as follow:-

```
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) {

 //have we expired?
    //redirect to logout.php
    header('Location: '.BASE_FULL_PATH.'/user/logout'); //change yoursite.com to the name of you site!!
} else{ //if we haven't expired:
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); //this was the moment of last activity.
}
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); 
$_SESSION['expire_time'] = 24*60*60;
```

and it is working perfectly but i need to have an alert box when the session is about to expire.Try lot of stuff but doesn't help.Please reply and thanks for your brilliant demo

Comment: It's not possible to do in PHP. You must use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I know , this is not an efficient way, But you can try this.
try ajax, that runs a php file in server every 5 or 10 second time gap.

that ajax running php file contains session last_activity and expire_time comparing code,

```
<?php
$warning=100;
if( $_SESSION['last_activity']+warning < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Your session will expire soon!");
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

You can set the variable $warning to adjust the alert message time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your session expiry will reset every time you reload the page, then you can use the expiry time as the time argument of JavaScript's `setTimeout()` function.

```
var sessionExpiryTime = 24 * 60 * 60;
var sessionExpiryAlertTime  = sessionExpiryTime - 5; //assuming we want the alert to show 5 seconds before expiry
setTimeout(function({ 
    alert("Session about to expire!");
}, sessionExpiryAlertTime * 1000); //time is in milliseconds so we multiply by 1000
```

This works okay as long as the user has JavaScript enabled. If the user reloads the page, the expiry timer updates as per your php code and the `setTimeout()` function restarts.